# Attempting To Combine These Two SQL Statements Into One

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been attempting to combine these two SQL statements into one.  However, I am having some trouble with it. Here they are:

```
string sql1 = "SELECT products.product_name 
                FROM products, order_details 
                WHERE products.id=order_details.product_id;";

string sql2 = "SELECT customers.first_name 
                FROM customers, orders 
                WHERE orders.customer_id=customers.id;";
```

I have been looking at using joins; however, I am getting confused on how to implement the WHERE statements.

Comment: You need to learn how to use ANSI `JOIN` with `ON` clauses. Then it becomes more obvious how to join multiple tables.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ANSI JOIN, then it's easy to see how to do multiple joins by relating each table in the sequence to another table.

```
SELECT c.first_name, p.product_name
FROM customers AS c
JOIN orders AS o ON c.id = o.customer_id
JOIN order_details AS od ON o.id = od.order_id
JOIN products AS p ON p.id = od.product_id
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes it a lot easier!